# Protractor getting to click a nested button element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I want to click on the second button,but i am not able to use by.class since it is same for both the buttons.

```
div class="ng-view ff-domain ng-scope">

<div class="hero-unit blur-background ng-scope">
    <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-warning btn-hero" href="/au/shop/glasses?gender=women"></a>
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-warning btn-hero" href="/au/shop/glasses?gender=men"></a>
    <div class="carousel ng-isolate-scope" carousel="" ng-mouseleave="play()" ng-mouseenter="pause()"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it several different ways, for example:

```
$('.hero-unit a:nth-clild(2)').click();
$('a[href="/au/shop/glasses?gender=men"]').click();
```

Check protractor API doc:

http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api

And take a look on css selectors:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var secondbtn = element.all(by.css(".btn").get(1);
secondbtn.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find the div that contains the desired links and distinguish the links based on the `href` attribute value - checking what the `href` ends with:

```
var container = element(by.css("div.hero-unit"));

var men = container.element(by.css("a[href$=men]"));
men.click();
```

Please note the readability of the suggested code.